# Trying to find cause of possible overflow in my approach when trying to solve

Tags: algorithm, number-theory

I am solving a question

> Find total numbers which are less than equal to A and are divisible by
>   both B and C.

I have written following function to compute the same

```
 public int solve(int A, int B, int C) {
        if(B==C){
            return A/B;
        }else{
            return A/(B*C);
        }
    }
```

Although this gives me correct answer but this is prone to overflow; which I suspect would be when we are multiplying b and c. I am not able to understand how can I correct this function to overcome the overflow.

> I am not looking for specific answer but more interested in knowing

1. Am I correct?
2. Hints towards the possible correction

Comment: How can this solve the problem of finding *all* numbers with that property? It returns only a single number.

Comment: I am sorry, My bad. Question description would be "find total numbers"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is *incorrect*. Counter example:

```
A = 100
B =  10
C =   8
```

- Expected: **2** (the numbers are `40` and `80`)
- Actual : **1** (`A / (B * C) == 100 / 80 == 1`)

The right formula is

```
A / (B * C / gcd(B, C))
```

where `gcd` stands for the [greatest common divisor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor)

Comment: Thank you; I tried to come with the intuition  for -> A* B/GCD(A,B) = B * A/GCD(A,B) = Numbers which are divisible by both A and B. Taking A 10 and B = 8; Can be written as 2 * 5 &  2 * 2 * 2 respectively. Now to find all the numebrs which are divisible by A and B, we take uncommn part * common part i.e gcd. we come up with 40 and then proceed with it.

Comment: We are trying to find all the multiplies of LCM(B,C)?

Comment: @Rishi: yes, `lcm(B, C) == B * C / gcd(B, C)`